# TypeScript type using Record utility

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-utility

```
    // OLD
    interface IData {
      missions: Missions
      items: Items
    }
    
    // Something new now
    type Keys = "missions" | "items"
    
    type INewDataType = Record<Keys, Missions | Items>
```

It won't work because in `INewDataType` type, items or missions can both have Missions or Items.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. What is your goal?

Comment: You're looking for [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), not `Record`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question here; it is true that you probably shouldn't use `INewDataType` if you want `IData`, but there doesn't seem to be any motivation to do so in the first place.  If I said "I have a can opener.  It won't work to use a fork to open a can", what would you say in response other than "right, use the can opener instead"?